# How to resolve huge matrix multiplication performance issue in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have huge .csv files (the biggest one, 72mb) that I need to load to my Android App. They contain matrices e.g [7500x1000], which I later use to multiply another one. Because their are too big to read them at one time () I'm reading line after line and perform some multiplication. I tested this on Nexus 4 and It took something about 15 minutes to do everything. When I copied the code from Android project to JAVA one(the only difference is that in Android i'm using Bitmap and in JAVA BufferedImage)  and ran this as java application it took few seconds. Do you have any idea why is so and how to shorten this time? Here Is my code:

Android:

```
public class NetworkThread extends Thread {
    private static boolean threadIsWorking = false;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteHandler sql;
    private static NetworkThread REFERENCE = null;

    private String w1 = "w1.csv";
    private String w2 = "w2.csv";
    private String w3 = "w3.csv";
    private String w4 = "w4.csv";
    String NEURON_PATH = "/data/data/com.ZPIProject/neuronFiles/";

    public static NetworkThread getInstance(Context context, SQLiteHandler sql) {
        if (REFERENCE == null)
            REFERENCE = new NetworkThread(context, sql);
        return REFERENCE;
    }

    private NetworkThread(Context context, SQLiteHandler sql) {
        this.context = context;
        this.sql = sql;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (!threadIsWorking) {
            threadIsWorking = true;

            try {
                Log.i("MATRIX", "THREAD ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.aparat_small);
                double[] imageInfo = ImageUtils.getImageInfo(bit);

                copyNeuronWeightsToMemoryOnPhone();

                double[] m4 = multiplyImageWithNeuronWeights(imageInfo);

                List<WeightWithId> best10 = findBest10Results(m4);

                for (int i = 0; i < best10.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("IDS", best10.get(i).getId() + "");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private List<WeightWithId> findBest10Results(double[] m4) throws SQLException, CloneNotSupportedException {
        List<WeightWithId> best10 = new ArrayList<WeightWithId>(20);

        for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
            Map<Integer, double[]> readDescriptions = sql.getDescriptionForShoeId(j * 100, j * 100 + 100);

            List<WeightWithId> distances = new ArrayList<WeightWithId>(100);
            for (Integer i : readDescriptions.keySet()) {
                double dist = dist(m4, readDescriptions.get(i));
                distances.add(new WeightWithId(i, dist));
            }

            Collections.sort(distances);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                best10.add(distances.get(i).clone());
            }

            Collections.sort(best10);
            if (best10.size() > 10) {
                for (int i = 10; i < best10.size(); i++) {
                    best10.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return best10;
    }

    private double[] multiplyImageWithNeuronWeights(double[] imageInfo) throws IOException {
        Log.i("MATRIX MULTIPLY", "M1");
        double[] m1 = MatrixMaker.multiplyMatrixWithCsvMatrix(NEURON_PATH + w1, imageInfo, 1000, false);
        Log.i("MATRIX MULTIPLY", "M2");
        double[] m2 = MatrixMaker.multiplyMatrixWithCsvMatrix(NEURON_PATH + w2, m1, 500, false);
        Log.i("MATRIX MULTIPLY", "M3");
        double[] m3 = MatrixMaker.multiplyMatrixWithCsvMatrix(NEURON_PATH + w3, m2, 250, false);
        Log.i("MATRIX MULTIPLY", "M4");
        return MatrixMaker.multiplyMatrixWithCsvMatrix(NEURON_PATH + w4, m3, 50, true);
    }

    private void copyNeuronWeightsToMemoryOnPhone() throws IOException {
        Log.i("MATRIX COPY", "W1");
        CopyUtils.copyFileIntoDevice(NEURON_PATH, w1, context);
        Log.i("MATRIX COPY", "W2");
        CopyUtils.copyFileIntoDevice(NEURON_PATH, w2, context);
        Log.i("MATRIX COPY", "W3");
        CopyUtils.copyFileIntoDevice(NEURON_PATH, w3, context);
        Log.i("MATRIX COPY", "W4");
        CopyUtils.copyFileIntoDevice(NEURON_PATH, w4, context);
    }

    private double dist(double[] a, double[] b) {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            result += (a[i] - b[i]) * (a[i] - b[i]);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Matrix Operations:

```
   public class MatrixMaker {

    public static double[] multiplyImageInfoWithCsvMatrix(String csvFilePath, double[] imageInfo, int expectedSize, boolean lastOne) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(csvFilePath));
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String line;

        //counter - to which position calculated value should be setted
        int counter = 0;
        //result array
        double[] multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix = new double[expectedSize + 1];
        //declaration of array for read line (parsed into double array)
        double[] singleLineFromCsv = new double[imageInfo.length];

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //splitting and parsing values from read line
            String[] splitted = line.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
                singleLineFromCsv[i] = Double.valueOf(splitted[i]);
            }

            //multiply imageInfo array with single row from csv file
            multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix[counter] = multiplyOneRow(imageInfo, singleLineFromCsv);
            //ugly flag 'lastOne' needed to other business case
            if (!lastOne) {
                multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix[counter] = 1d / (1 + Math.exp(-multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix[counter]));
            }
            counter++;
            //logging progress
            if (counter % 100 == 0)
                Log.i("MULTIPLY PROGRESS", counter + " " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
        if (!lastOne)
            multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix[expectedSize] = 1d;

        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        return multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix;
    }

    private static double multiplyOneRow(double first[], double second[]) {
        double result = 0d;
        for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
            result += first[i] * second[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

onCreate in one of Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        final SQLiteHandler sql = new SQLiteHandler(this);
        sql.init();
        NetworkThread.getInstance(this, sql).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

JAVA:

Multiply equivalent of Matrix Maker

```
import java.io.*;

public class Multiply {

    public static double[] multiplyMatrixWithCsvMatrix(String csvFilePath, double[] imageInfo,
                                                   int expectedSize, boolean lastOne) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(csvFilePath));
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        String line;

        // counter - to which position calculated value should be setted
        int counter = 0;
        // result array
       double[] multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix = new double[expectedSize + 1];
        // declaration of array for read line (parsed into double array)
        double[] singleLineFromCsv = new double[imageInfo.length];

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // splitting and parsing values from read line
            String[] splitted = line.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
                singleLineFromCsv[i] = Double.valueOf(splitted[i]);
            }

            // multiply imageInfo array with single row from csv file
            multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix[counter] = multiplyOneRow(imageInfo, singleLineFromCsv);
            // ugly flag 'lastOne' needed to other business case
            if (!lastOne) {
                multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix[counter] = 1d / (1 + Math
                        .exp(-multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix[counter]));
            }
            counter++;
            // logging progress
            if (counter % 100 == 0)
                System.out.println(counter + " " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
        if (!lastOne)
            multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix[expectedSize] = 1d;

        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        return multipliedImageInfoWithCsvMatrix;
    }

    private static double multiplyOneRow(double first[], double second[]) {
        double result = 0d;
        for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
            result += first[i] * second[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Executable class

```
public class MRunner {

    private static final int RED_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int GREEN_INDEX = 2500;
    private static final int BLUE_INDEX = 5000;
    private static final String w1 = "w1.csv";
    private static final String NEURON_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Vortim\\Desktop\\";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Multiply.multiplyMatrixWithCsvMatrix(NEURON_PATH + w1, getImageInfo(ImageIO
                            .read(new File("C:\\Users\\Vortim\\git\\MatrixMaker\\but.png"))), 1000,
                            false);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();

    }

    public static double[] getImageInfo(BufferedImage source) {
        double[] result = new double[7501];
        int width = source.getWidth();
        int height = source.getHeight();

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                if (x == 0) {
                    result[y + RED_INDEX] = 255d;
                    result[y + GREEN_INDEX] = 255d;
                    result[y + BLUE_INDEX] = 255d;
                } else if (y == 0) {
                    result[x * 50 + RED_INDEX] = 255d;
                    result[x * 50 + GREEN_INDEX] = 255d;
                    result[x * 50 + BLUE_INDEX] = 255d;
                } else {
                    int pixel = source.getRGB(x, y);
                    double r = (pixel) >> 16 & 0xff;
                    double g = (pixel) >> 8 & 0xff;
                    double b = (pixel) & 0xff;

                    result[x * y + RED_INDEX] = 1d - (r / 255d);
                    result[x * y + GREEN_INDEX] = 1d - (g / 255d);
                    result[x * y + BLUE_INDEX] = 1d - (b / 255d);
                }
            }
        }
        result[7500] = 1;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a *wall of text*. You can't expect too many of us to read all this. Use a profiler (ddms) to find the hotspots. Obviously it's something Android specific, so you should try to isolate the problem on one of the differences between the android version and the desktop version.

Comment: Use Traceview to determine specifically where you are spending all your time.

Comment: I would upload the data to a server, perform the multiplication there and download the result.  Phones are not designed to do this sort of work whereas you can can do this on a GPU in seconds.

Comment: Wait a second, it looks like an app for finding similar shoes, am I correct?